# Ruby on Rails 3 bundle for textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

Whether there is a bundle(ror 3) for textmate?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
git clone git://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle.git "Ruby on Rails.tmbundle"
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Comment: I try it. But as I understood, it to branch rails 2 .* ?

Comment: In the validation of there old "validation_length_of" & etc.

Comment: it's not really deprecated but I agree it can feel not up to date. Check out the forks https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle/network or DIY I guess

Comment: btw it should be present https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle/commit/eb5f07735b5edd8908f6dd60de34136db44f9c23

Answer (score 1):

In Textmate 2 you can install it directly from the program:

1. In the menu: TextMate > Preferences..
2. Click on the "Bundles" Tab
3. Scroll down and click the checkbox next to "Ruby on Rails"